# Pitch changing plugin for Winamp?

Tags: software-rec, plugins, winamp, real-time, audio-processing

Is there a free Winamp plugin that can change the pitch of the music (in real time, so no Audacity or stuff like that) by a number of semitones? The ones I've found are either not free or too old.

Alternatively, what others music players support this feature natively or as a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PaceMaker](http://www.surina.net/pacemaker/) can change pitch or tempo in real time. When you change the values, it takes about a second to take effect due to Winamp's internal buffer. You can decrease the buffer size (Preferences, Plug-ins, Output) to make the changes take effect faster if you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Aimp](http://aimp.ru/index.php) can natively change the pitch - but it's a simple slider so you cannot control it in detail.

For better control you can try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/)

Comment: About Audacity, see my edit.